# wordpress get post where category is not equal to blog

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to get the latest post which is not a blog . I know how to get a post by category name but how to get the post which is not equal to a specific category name . Here is the code i use to get for a category name

```
$query = array (
    'category_name' => 'Blog',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => array('publish')   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) you can use 'category__not_in' and feed it the id of the category you want to exclude.

```
$args = array(
    'category__not_in' => array($id), // Pass in one or more IDs here.
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish', // no need to pass it in a array
    'orderby' => 'date' // Since you wanted the latest post, this is default value so not really needed
);
```

You can find out the ID of the category by hovering the category-link in the WP-backend and go to the category and then check the adress in your adress-bar, it should look something like this:

```
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `category_not_in` query parameter. To use it you'll need the ID, not the slug, of the category you want to exclude from your result.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

```
$BlogObj = get_category_by_slug('Blog'); 
$query = array (
    'category_not_in' => array($BlogObj->term_id),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => array('publish')   
);
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help . Tried this but not working :(

Comment: Don't forget. The point of StackOverflow is to help you find out new strategies and new ways of thinking about hard problems. We can't debug everything for you: we don't have you knowledge of your environment or problem.

Comment: I totally agree with you . Your post helped me learn something new . I am working out for a solution checking everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$query = array (
    'category_not_in' => array(get_cat_ID('Blog'),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'   
);
```

Comment: Category not in is not working in  my case its still showing the post under Blog category :(

Comment: Check this `echo get_cat_ID('Blog')` somewhere in your template and make sure you get the right `id`.

Comment: when i see from admin panel it says `taxonomy=category&tag_ID=26&post_type=post` and when i echo it says `26` . The id is right